# Some exported symbols disappear after creating a dynamic framework with the ios_framework rule

Tags: ios, objective-c, bazel

I am facing quite a strange situation trying to build a mixed-language dynamic iOS framework with Bazel.

The source code of the framework consists of *.c, *.cpp, *.m, *.mm, *.h, *.hpp files.

My first naive attempt was to declare a single objc_library rule referencing all the sources. That failed with an error message reading something about conflicting rules. Then I declared four distinct `objc_library` rules for *.m, *.mm, *.c, and *.cpp files respectively, and then referenced all these four rules as dependencies for the final `ios_framework` rule.

At this point, everything compiled and linked just fine (barring several compiler warnings which were expected). However, now the black magic begins:

- The static library resulting from compiling ObjectiveC++ sources **does** contain all the necessary symbols (verified with the "nm" tool)
- The .apple_binary_lipobin file resulting from the linking phase **does not** contain symbols from ObjectiveC++ sources

I believe I carefully went through the command lines used for compiling and linking, both for Bazel and xcodebuild.

The only anomalies I was able to spot:

- xcodebuild passes a `-single_module` argument when linking, while Bazel cross tool does not.
- Bazel cross tool adds `'-stdlib=libc++' '-std=gnu++11'` command line arguments when invoking `wrapped_clang_pp` during linking, while xcodebuild does not pass these arguments. I guess Bazel does this because there're these lines in the default Apple CROSSTOOL:

  `action_config {
    config_name: "objc++-executable"
    action_name: "objc++-executable"
    tool {
      tool_path: "wrapped_clang_pp"
      execution_requirement: "requires-darwin"
    }
    flag_set {
      flag_group {
      flag: "-stdlib=libc++"
      flag: "-std=gnu++11"
    }`

but I am not sure if these flags are really needed when invoking the linker.

I must admit I've run out of ideas except for trying to patch the CROSSTOOl file to make it behave as close as xcodebuild as possible.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try adding `alwayslink = 1` to the `objc_library` target containing the C++ symbols? The linker is deadstripping the C++ symbols as they are not being referenced anywhere in the binary.

Comment: Thanks - will try that! It’s strange though that xcodebuild doesn’t specify this flag (but on the other hand, xcodebuild does not need intermediate static libraries to link the final Mach-O shared lib)